# Buffer and pointers in Delphi from C DLL

Tags: function, delphi, pointers, dll, buffer

I am still learning from the DLL process and since no Delphi FTDI Libmpsse library exist, I must work my own way through with the DLL from scratch.

However, I'm far from perfect in Delphi!
I've been using it for few years without touching pointers.

This is the particular line I'm now stuck with (This is what I've tried to translate):

```
function I2C_DeviceWrite(
  handle              :dword;
  deviceAddress       :uint32;
  sizeToTransfer      :uint32;
  out buffer          :byte;
  out sizeTransferred :uint32;
  options             :uint32
):FT_Result; cdecl; external 'libmpsse.dll';
```

From the API User guide it is describe the C way like this:

```
FT_STATUS I2C_DeviceWrite(
  FT_HANDLE handle, 
  uint32    deviceAddress,
  uint32    sizeToTransfer, 
  uint8    *buffer, 
  uint32   *sizeTransferred,
  uint32    options )
```

Asterix means pointer in C from what I understand.

I don't know how to declare them properly yet.

Any hints?

NB: I'm still reading (XE2 Foundations) and searching about pointers and buffers the most I can!

Thank you!

BTW, API Guide is here for consulation:[PDF from FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_177_User_Guide_For_LibMPSSE-I2C.pdf)

EDIT:

```
var
Buffer: array of Byte;
written,towrite:cardinal;
begin
SetLength(Buffer,I2C_DEVICE_BUFFER_SIZE);
buffer[0] := $07;
towrite := 1;
i2c_openchannel(1,FT_HANDLE); //open channel 1
i2c_initchannel(FT_HANDLE,I2C_CLOCK_STANDARD_MODE and LATENCY_TIMER and 0);
i2c_devicewrite(FT_HANDLE,I2C_DEVICE_ADDRESS,towrite,buffer,written,I2C_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_START_BIT);
i2c_closechannel(FT_HANDLE); //close device
```

So far so good everything else work except the i2c_devicewrite line!
It gives me E2033:unable to compile actual and formal var parameters must be identical

Comment: OT: define a type of `FT_HANDLE`; use data types from the original code (types as `UInt32` exist in Delphi for a while).

Comment: Cardinals aren't the same? FT_HANDLE is defined like this in my code: Var --> FT_HANDLE : DWord = 0;//it must always be 0 from the API

Comment: If the original code asks for `uint32`, declare your type as `uint32` and you don't have to worry about whether or not cardinal is the same. If the type is already declared in Delphi, *use the type that is already declared*. How is `FT_HANDLE` defined in the user's guide **exactly**?

Comment: FT_Handle is defined as a DWORD. Thanks for the tip! Edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Another shameless tip: my article [Pitfalls of converting](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html) describes most of this. Also read [Addressing pointers](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html).

Comment: Thank you Rudy! Very useful, you should write a Delphi book! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've translated the byte array parameter incorrectly. You used

```
out buffer: byte
```

which is a single byte, passed out by reference. It should be

```
buffer: PByte
```

which here means a pointer to array of byte.

Then pass the address of the first element of the array. Like this:

```
@Buffer[0]
```

or like this

```
PByte(Buffer)
```

Note that I've not checked anything other than the byte array parameter.

FWIW, a constant length array may be simpler here than a dynamic array.

I'd also comment that you appear to be ignoring return values. Never do that. Always check return values for errors.

Comment: *sizeTransferred ... it has a asterisk append to it from C means pointer... sorry forgot to update the main question.

Comment: From the PDF: (out) sizeTransferred: Pointer to variable containing the number of bytes
read

Comment: You declared it as an out parameter and that means the address of the variable is passed. Please read your earlier question on the subject that I answered.

Comment: Remember also that you asked about a compilation error. There can be no doubt that my answer resolves that error.

Comment: I've tried every possible ways to understand it since yesterday still have the same compilation error. I have my head plunged in the Adressing pointers article of Rudy Velthius for a while still have trouble with pointers.

Comment: I just compiled the code by making the changes I described. Your problem is likely that you've changed more than I said to. Start with the code in the Q and make the changes as per my answer. Your current flailing won't yield good results. Go slowly and understand what you are doing.

Comment: It compiles but the problem was PByte(Buffer) that give me Invalid typecast everytime! However I get 0 for written bytes... I need to test further!

Comment: FWIW, it's Velthuis, not Velthius.

Comment: Invalid typecast is a compiler error. And `PByte(Buffer)` is a valid typecast. One more time. My answer fixes your compiler error. You don't appear to check return values. Why not?

Comment: @David: you didn't miswrite it, ELCouz did. Anyway, it is always a problem if people do not do exactly what others tell them to, and then complain it doesn't work. ISTM that misspelling other people's name is another symptom of the same problem. ;-)

Comment: @Rudy English is not my mother tongue so I have the re-read few times to be sure I've understood correctly the answer. I'm sorry for the typo, i'm not perfect either.

Comment: @ELCouz: it is not my mother tongue either. But names are names, and it is quite simple to copy them. If you did exactly what David said, it should work. Which part did you not understand? 1. Change the parameter to `Buffer: PByte` and 2. call the function with `I2C_DeviceWrite( ... PByte(Buffer) ... );`. If you did not change anything else, it should work.

Comment: @David I wasn't checking the return values because at the beginning I wanted to show a simple code just to barely get it to compile. Now I've seen that my return values are bad (1: invalid handle & 6: invalid parameter) I have to dig around an old delphi 5 code from FTDI to help me.

Comment: You can't expect us to debug your entire program. Just answer the question you asked. I think that's been done.

Comment: i2c_devicewrite(FT_HANDLE,I2C_DEVICE_ADDRESS,towrite,pbyte(Buffer),written,I2C_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_START_BIT);
Gives me Invalid typecast but @buffer works

Comment: I'm not expecting anyone to debug my code it's just the Pbyte(buffer) didn't worked out. That's why I didn't accepted the answer.

Comment: function I2C_DeviceWrite(handle:dword;deviceAddress:uint32;sizeToTransfer:uint32;buffer:pbyte;out sizeTransferred:uint32;options:uint32):FT_Result; cdecl; external 'libmpsse.dll'; the function is exactly what you want

Comment: It compiles here. Clearly you did something wrong. You must have changed the definition of `buffer`. You changed it from `array of byte` to `byte`. As @Rudy says, attention to detail is critical. You need to go more slowly and pay more attention to detail.

Comment: @David Your question has been accepted because you help me the most has you could. Thank you!

Comment: var
  Buffer:array [0..I2C_DEVICE_BUFFER_SIZE] of Byte; Always like that since yesterday.

Comment: Do you expect us to be answer the question based on what your code looks like rather than what you asked in the question? Ask yourself how we could do that?

Comment: A constant sized buffer should be `var Buffer:array [0..I2C_DEVICE_BUFFER_SIZE-1] of Byte;` and you would pass `@Buffer[0]` in that case.

Comment: Your real problem is you inability to change one thing at a time and tackle a problem methodically. You should concentrate on improving your problem solving method.

Comment: I wanted to delete the question. It won't bring any help to stackoverflow because it is badly formulated. However, I can't because people took time to answer it. So i'll leave it just like that.

Comment: These type of questions never help anyone other than the asker. Conceptually this question has been asked hundreds of times, and I (and others) have answered over and over again. That's fine. What I really hope is that you try to learn how to work a problem. That is your real opportunity now.